# How to solve a problem with a higher order function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I don't seem to fully understand how "closing" works. I have an input when changing which I need to call functions and pass 2 arguments to it. But I also need the event of this event.

My version below doesn't work. Only the first part of the function will work, and the second (where I return the second function) does not work. I can not, unfortunately, understand what is my mistake and how to make the "closure" to the end.

And the second, mini, question - how exactly to type event here if I'm working in react?

```tsx
const handleChangeClosure = (userId: string, role: string) => (event: ???) => {
  const { checked } = event.target;
  dispatch(addOrDeleteRoleAction(userId, role, checked, dispatch));
};

<input type="checkbox" onChange={() => handleChangeClosure(user.userId, "Controller")}/>
```

Comment: We explicitly ask people to not say hello or thank you as it clutters the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={() => handleChangeClosure(user.userId, "Controller")}/>
```

With

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeClosure(user.userId, "Controller")}/>
```

The `handleChangeClosure` function returns a function and the `onChange` event expects a function. So you don't need `()=>` which would just wrap it in another function.

Alternatively, this would also work:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={(ev) => handleChangeClosure(user.userId, "Controller")(ev)}/>
```

But that's just more useless code.

Comment: @Phil True, the lint rules my company uses enforces the type anyway but you are correct it's not necessary for typescript.

Answer (score 0):

By using `onChange={() => ...}`, you're losing the `event` argument.

What you want is

```tsx
<input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChangeClosure(user.userId, "Controller")}/>
```

Your higher-order-function returns a new *event handler* function that will be attached to the *change* event.

FYI the type for `event` is `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

```ts
const handleChangeClosure =
  (userId: string, role: string) =>
  (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { checked } = event.target;
    dispatch(addOrDeleteRoleAction(userId, role, checked, dispatch));
  };
```